# Visual Studio 2005 Shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, shortcut

I'm trying to bind the following shortcut: **Ctrl + W** to close tabs

How can you customize VS to add/change shortcuts?  Also, what are the most useful shortcuts you guys have found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools > Options > (Show all settings), then Environment > Keyboard.

Here, rebind the key “File.Close” to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

I keep a link to Jeff's [shortcuts page](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202005%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.htm), and refer to it to learn the shortcuts for all tasks I find myself regularly doing. I also use VisualAssist, and use a lot of:

- toggling between .h and .cpp files (yes, I code in C++ :) ) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>);
- going to the definition of something (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>).

Answer (score 3):

VS 2005/2008 Keybinding posters:

- [Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference
  Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en)
- [Visual C# 2005 Keyboard
  Shortcut Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C15D210D-A926-46A8-A586-31F8A2E576FE&displaylang=en)
- [Visual Basic 2008 Keybinding
  Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255b8cf1-f6bd-4b55-bb42-dd1a69315833&displaylang=en)
- [Visual Basic
  2005 Keyboard Shortcut Reference
  Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6BB41456-9378-4746-B502-B4C5F7182203&displaylang=en)

These don't cover customizations but they're good reference materials and definitely helpful for finding new shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

I find most of them useful TBH!

Commenting, Bookmarking, Incremental Search, etc etc.

The one you want to override by the way is *Window.CloseDocumentWindow* which defaults to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> shows the syntax/overloads for the current function you are typing parameters for.