# Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts

Tags: .net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What is your favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcut?  I'm always up for leaving my hands on the keyboard and away from the mouse!

**One** per answer please.

Comment: Same questions have been asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507/give-me-awesome-visual-studio-keyboard-short-cuts and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452/visual-studio-2005-shortcuts

Comment: the correct thing to do is relate these by tagging them similarly

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut to scroll to the start of the next or previous function? CTRL + UP or DOWN cursor key used to do this in VB and I really miss it.

Comment: Eh, programmers and their keyboard shortcuts :) Apple proved long ago that they are usually slower than using the mouse (except for certain repeated sequences of actions), but they make you *feel* like you're going faster. That said, I'm a programmer, so I use a lot of shortcuts :) I find the toolbar buttons just fine, though, for commenting/uncommenting, navigating forward/backward, etc. Especially if your hand is already on the mouse. (An old but good reference: http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi06KeyboardVMouse1.html.)

Comment: I think that's a load. I am much, much faster using only the keyboard than the mouse. I in fact HATE my mouse. Sucks that it is a necessity.

Comment: @DanM, anything that "Apple proved" needs to be taken with a grain of salt.  How is hunting for and moving the mouse to a small patch of pixels ever going to be quicker than a memorized key shortcut?  Seriously, get your hand of it and back onto the keyboard ;)

Comment: @Ash, you underestimate the time it takes to recall a piece of information and the time it takes to think. The time it takes to push keys on a keyboard is less than the time it takes to move a mouse to a small patch of pixels, but the time to prepare is far more. You don't notice the passage of time while you're recalling Ctrl-Shift-Whatever, but if you get out the stopwatch, it will be there. There are exceptions to every rule, so yeah, you may be quicker using Ctrl-Z than choosing Undo from the Edit menu, but for anything you don't use 100 times a day, I bet you're slower.

Comment: ...I found this one even more amazing: http://www.asktog.com/SunWorldColumns/S02KeyboardVMouse3.html

Comment: @DanM, but that's just the point, muscle memory means there preparation time is virtually non-existent (any thinking is subconcious).  This is what touch typing is entirely based on.  I'm not a touch typer, but I can type memorized shortcut keys faster than I could verbalise what I have actually typed.  In programming there are shortcuts that are less commonly used, so these can take longer to memorize, however this is where mnemonics can help.

Comment: @Ash, I don't dispute what you're saying about muscle memory, but it takes thousands of repetitions to build up muscle memory to the point that it becomes subconscious. I don't see that happening for most keyboard shortcuts, except for the ones you really use constantly (like cut, copy, paste, undo).

Comment: @DanM, its not an all or nothing scenario.  Using cursor keys to move to *arbitrary* positions in a document is silly, use the mouse.  But as you get more experienced with shortcuts, keys are simply quicker for most other things.   With the mouse, you're also having to deal with hand eye coordination, meaning it can be very fiddly.  Suggestion: Try to focus on using keys more, for a month or so.  You may find it hard going to start with, but your productivity will greatly benefit if you stick at it.  But sticking at it is the key.

Comment: @Ash, maybe we're not even disagreeing. I use a number of keyboard shortcuts and cursor keys all the time. My original comment was specifically dealing with some of the obscure shortcuts people were mentioning in this thread. I don't think my productivity would "greatly improve", for example, if I used Ctrl-K Ctrl-C every time I wanted to comment a block of code. A lot of times, I'm already selecting a block of code with the mouse, so it's quite natural and easy to click the "comment" button on the toolbar (and I bet you it's faster).

Comment: Ctrl + R + E = to create the equivalent Property of the fields.

Answer (score 227):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and the opposite <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

Move cursor back (or forwards) to the last place it was. No more scrolling back or <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to find out where you were.

This switches open windows in Visual Studio:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and the opposite <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: This is made even better when you bind them to 'application specific' back and forward mouse buttons!

Comment: I've been looking for this forever. I used to just use Ctrl+Z Ctrl+Y.

Comment: Ctrl-Tab is a bit funny in VS for some reason - it doesn't just cycle like most apps.

Comment: @Lucas Jones, It seems to cycle like Alt-Tab in Windows. Seems normal to me.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl + Tab once swaps between the current document and previous document, you don't even need to look at the popup window.

Comment: I often cancel cycling between application windows (Alt+Tab) by pressing Esc. Doing so while cycling through document windows (Ctrl+Tab), however, pops up Windows' start menu. That just drives me nuts.

Comment: @Lucas Jones: In VS2010, Ctrl+Tab is mapped by default to Window.NextDocumentWindowNav, which provides the "Alt+Tab"-like behavior. I've remappe Ctrl+Tab to Window.NextDocumentWindow which works similarly to the "cycling" behavior. Hope that helps!

Comment: The cursor positions are on the standard keyboard. I added the numeric keypad keys `Ctrl+Num+Minus` and `Ctrl+Num+Plus`. These are more intuitive than minus and shift-minus. This steals them from a design view zoom, which I never use.

Comment: VS should allow choosing windows using `Ctrl+<Num>` like `Ctrl+1 for first window. It is possible in Firefox

Answer (score 130):

For me, it's nothing to do about auto completing code, matching parenthesis or showing some fancy tool panel. Instead, it's just about *letting me see the code.*

With all the panels surrounding you, the area you use to actually write code becomes too small.

In this cases, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> comes in to the rescue and gets the code window in focus in *full screen* mode. Hit it again, and you have all the panels back.

Comment: I always use Alt+V, U for the same effect :) But yeah fullscreen mode rocks.

Comment: BIG monitors work too =)

Comment: Agreed!  I use this one all the time.  VS10 will have floating panels which will help somewhat.

Comment: Having all the extra windows unpinned when in edit mode helps too.

Answer (score 124):

Incremental Search - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

It's basically the find dialog box without the dialog box.  Just start typing what you want to search for (look at the bottom status bar location to see what you've typed).  Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> again or <kbd>F3</kbd> searches for the next instance.  Press Escape to quit.  Starting a new search by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> twice repeats the last search.

Comment: Plus, it finds the first instance as you type. Ctrl-i after you hit a match searches to the next instance - and keeps you in search mode (which means you can add or change the search string). The search box is for suckers!

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know that, although I had on some occasions hit ctrl+I by mistake and wondered what the odd mouse pointer meant. :)

Comment: One caveat with this that I've seen (in VS 2005 any way), it only searches through visible text.  So if you have some collapsed in a region, for example, it won't search that.  I don't know if this is a feature or a bug!

Comment: Sounds like the emacs search feature.

Comment: @Adam: In my experience, the fact that VS ignores hidden text (e.g. inside collapsed regions) makes this feature almost useless. Incremental search is an awesome feature, I just with they hadn't crippled it in VS.

Comment: @CodeSavvyGeek: It's fixed in VS2010.

Comment: Hidden text not searcheable? This should be called excremental search, lol. VS2010 sp1 searches the hidden text too.

Comment: Actually, it is now in 2012 kind of merged with search(ctrl+f) into one feature

Answer (score 98):

Expand Smart Tag (Resolve Menu): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period)

Expands the tag that shows when you do things like rename an identifier.

Comment: Best shortcut ever.  Use when you see a squiggly "~", under some code. : )

Comment: This is my fave and only one I can remember.  Alt-Enter is similar if you have resharper installed.

Comment: Also Shift-Alt-F10 is bound to this but probably harder

Comment: Good shortcut, but what it actually does is bring up the "Resolve" menu (so you can add a `using` statement or fully qualified namespace for a class)...it has nothing to do with tooltips.

Comment: DanThMan, you're right, tooltip isn't the correct terminology, will update

Comment: This combine key may be called: quick fix (as equivalent in Eclipse: Ctrl + 1).

Answer (score 95):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> Comment a block
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> Uncomment the block

Comment: Ctrl K, D formats the entire document (proper indents, ws cleaned up, etc.) in mine. ?

Comment: I typically customize the mapping to be CTRL+/ (comment) and CTRL+SHIFT+/ (uncomment). I find that nice and intuitive.

Comment: Ctrl-E, C and Ctrl-E, U also works. You dont have to release Ctrl after the first key either.

Comment: I use CTRL+/ withy Resharper.Resharper_LineComment which with one shortcut toggles line comments on and off.

Comment: I use this often so I like to customize this as well to something easy on the fingers: 
Alt-[ to uncomment, and Alt-] to comment.

Answer (score 77):

Stock Visual Studio? <kbd>F12</kbd> - *Edit.GoToDefinition*.

Having DevExpress' Refactor! installed means that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> is my all-time fave, though  ;)

Comment: -1, favor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/98826#98826 (But second CodeRush, though I tie it to Num 0)

Comment: love this and it couples well with [Control]+[-]

Answer (score 71):

The <kbd>TAB</kbd> key for "snippets".

E.g. type `try` and then hit the tab key twice.

Results in:

```
try 
{           

}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

which you can then expand.

Full list of C# Snippets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z41h7fat.aspx

Comment: Fantastic - knew about snippets, but not that you could get to them so quickly!

Answer (score 61):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for matching braces and parentheses.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> selects code between matching parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike most other keyboard shortcuts this one is language neutral. For example on a Danish keyboard it is CTRL+Å. For all the different ones see this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio

Comment: wow this one is great for looking through loooong lines of code someone else wrote

Answer (score 60):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Good old *Find In Files*.

Answer (score 51):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Visual Studio gives the possible completions.

Answer (score 47):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>*,* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> // Auto-(Re)Format

See Also: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452/visual-studio-2005-shortcuts#36666)

Comment: Particularly useful for messy XML files.

Comment: to my VS, is CTRL + K, CTRL + Y :)

Comment: and for me it's CTRL + K, CTRL + F

Answer (score 43):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to duplicate the current line
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to delete the current line
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to search for the current selection
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to create a bookmark (which are useful)  
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to go to the next bookmark

And, here is something even more interesting:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to put the cursor into a box where you can type commands. 
For example, Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and type ">of ", now start typing the name of a file in your project, and it will autocomplete. This is a very fast way to open files in the current solution.

Comment: Control-L cuts the current line.  Control-Shift-L deletes it.

Comment: @Greg: Class, thanks. @Others: These are great ones, but fail to adhere to the questioner's  one per line ask :- -1 :(

Comment: Also dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/101873#101873

Comment: Ctrl + D duplicates the current line as well (and much shorter)

Comment: Ctrl+/ is great. Anyone know if there are any good docs on the commands I can use with this?

Comment: @Ray: Ctrl + D isn't working for me. Is that with default Visual Studio shortcuts? It might be a ReSharper shortcut IIRC?

Comment: Yeah, I realised later (and updated my answer, but not my comment) that it's a resharper shortcut.

Comment: I have been using ctrl + x, ctrl + v for repeat a whole line, ctrl + x, cut a line :)

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste / cycle through the clipboard ring

Comment: I've always found this feature too slow to be of any use. I wish they would improve its performance - sometimes its takes up to 20 seconds to load the items in the clipboard.

Comment: Use clipx if you want to do clipboard history.  It spans all applications.  http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/

Comment: in 2012 working great! than you :)

Comment: Wow this is awesome.  This is a nice helper for all those times I thought I had "lost" my previous clipboard contents, it was still there the whole time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.  To expand/collapse the current code block.

Comment: Seems like ctrl + m + m works as well.  So you don't have to release the ctrl button after the first m.

Comment: Every one of shortcuts is editable and the default often is that there is version with ctrl two times or the firts time.

Answer (score 34):

One that I use often but not many other people do is:

> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you type in a class name like `Collection<string>` and do not have the proper namespace import then this shortcut combination will automatically insert the import (while the carret is immediately after the '>').

**Update:**

An equivalent shortcut from the comments on this answer (thanks [asterite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20459/asterite)!):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Much more comfortable than my original recommendation.

Comment: This is for View.SHowSmartTag so any smart tag that appears will have their menu openw ith this (e.g., implement interface). I change this mapping to Alt+Down arrow.

Comment: I tend to hit Windows button -> down -> right -> enter, which to me is faster than repositioning my hands in a weird way in order to press Shift+Alt+F10+Enter.

Comment: You can do Ctrl + "." for the same purpose, and it's much, much more comfortable.

Comment: Yes, you can do Ctrl+".", but the original Shift + Alt + F10 will also work in other MS applications such as Outlook, PowerPoint, Excel and Word.

Comment: -1 as dup of one above (even if this was first, not surte if it was)

Answer (score 34):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>

This hides/closes any of the 'fake window' windows in Visual Studio. This includes things like the Solution Explorer, Object Browser, Output Window, Immediate window, Unit Test Windows etc. etc. and still applies whether they're pinned, floating, dockable or tabbed.

Shortcut into a window (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) do what you need to do, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get rid of it. If you don't get rid of it, the only way to give it focus again is to use the same keyboard shortcut (or the mouse, which is what we're trying to avoid....)

Once you get the hang of it, it's immensely useful.

---

*Grrr....The amount of times of hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to close the 'window' only to see my current code window close was insane before I found this, now it only happens occasionally..*

Comment: This is awesome!!!  (shift+esc)  I always build, have the output window fly out and have the mouse cursor hovering, which prevents it from autohiding.  This makes me move my hands off the keyboard, which I HATE.  But thanks to this, you've solved my single biggest annoyance with visual studio.  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU.

Comment: "If you don't get rid of it, the only way to give it focus again is to use the same keyboard shortcut" - Alt+F6 cycles through open tool windows, faster to press than Ctrl-W-stuff

Comment: On MSVC 6.0 (or something even older?) [ESC] did the hiding (actually toggling IIRC) the output window. I have looked a long time for a replacement to that one, thanks!

Comment: VS 2012 use Ctrl+Shift+[ instead of Ctrl+Alt+L - which navigates to the current file instead of navigating to last selected file in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 24):

My favorite: <kbd>F12</kbd> (go to definition) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (find references). 
The latter is useful with <kbd>F8</kbd> (go to next result).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> are mapped to my mouse's back and forwards buttons.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is useful too, especially for adding event handlers and "using" statements.

Comment: I use <menu key>, <g> for go to definition.  Its much easier to reach than F12.  <menu key>, <a> will do find all references, too.  Most of the time when I'm browsing code, I have my left hand on keyboard and my right hand on the mouse, which means I can right click and press <g> or <a> for these as well, which is pretty quick.

Answer (score 24):

Visual Studio 2005/2008 keybinding posters:

- [Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference
  Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en)
- [Visual C# 2005 Keyboard
  Shortcut Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C15D210D-A926-46A8-A586-31F8A2E576FE&displaylang=en)
- [Visual Basic 2008 Keybinding
  Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255b8cf1-f6bd-4b55-bb42-dd1a69315833&displaylang=en)
- [Visual Basic
  2005 Keyboard Shortcut Reference
  Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6BB41456-9378-4746-B502-B4C5F7182203&displaylang=en)

These don't cover customizations, but they're good reference materials and definitely helpful for finding new shortcuts.

Also, a macro that dumps all the current bindings to a HTML file:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000315.html

Comment: VS 2010: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f

Answer (score 22):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrow keys(<kbd>←</kbd>,<kbd>↑</kbd>,<kbd>↓</kbd>,<kbd>→</kbd>)

This allow you to select things in a block.  Like you could select all of the "int" in the block and then search and replace to double for example.

```
**int** x = 1;
**int** y = 2;
**int** z = 3;
```

Comment: Hey, i'm pretty sure this is acutally CTRL not ALT in all of the above examples...

Answer (score 19):

Open and set focus in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: I usually hit "Esc" to get back.

Comment: Also, for ReSharper users, Alt+Shift+L focuses on the current file in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>. Can collapse and expand all sections of code in a particular file.

Comment: VS O8 link has been removed from the destination site. It says, due to possible copyright infringement.

Comment: It's not Ctrl+M,0 but Ctrl+M,O (<- not zero but an O)

Comment: If you want to expand again use CTRL + M, P

Answer (score 18):

One that other editors should take up:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with *nothing selected* will copy the current line.
Most other editors will do nothing.  After copying a line, pasting will place the line before the current one, *even if you're in the middle of the line*.  Most other editors will start pasting from where you are, which is almost never what you want.

Duplicating a line is just: Hold Ctrl, press c, then v.
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Comment: This could also be annoying if you press Ctrl+C by mistake instead of Ctrl+V

Comment: And CodeRush adds even more w/ Ctrl W and auto stuff on Ctrl-C....

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (Start Without Debugging)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Build Solution)

Comment: F7 is "build solution" for me.

Comment: How to build not the entire but the selected solution??

Answer (score 14):

Here is a list that I use frequently:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>: for progressive search. If you don't type anything after <kbd>I</kbd>, and keep pressing <kbd>I</kbd> (holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down), it will search the last item you had searched. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> will reverse search. You might also want to use <kbd>F3</kbd> (and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>) once some search string is entered.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: For commenting highlighted region. If nothing is highlighted, current line will be commented. Naturally, you can just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> in succession.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>: For uncommenting highlighted region. Works like above.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>: Will take the cursor to the small search box on top. You can type **">of filename"** (without the quotes) to open a file. Very useful if your project contains multiple files.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>: Will bookmark the current line. This is useful if you want to look at some other part of code for a moment and come back to where you were.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>: Will take you to the next bookmark, if there are more than one.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>: Will take the cursor to its previous location

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>: Will take the cursor to its next location (if it exists)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>: Build your project

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: Although this does the usual copy, if nothing is highlighted, it copies the current line. Same for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> (for cut)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>: Autocomplete using IntelliSense

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>: Will take you to the matching brace. Works with all kinds of braces: '(', '{', '['. Useful for big blocks.

<kbd>F12</kbd>: Will take you to the function definition/variable definition.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>: Will open up project properties. Although not many use this, it useful if you want to quickly change the command line arguments to your program.

<kbd>F5</kbd>: To start debugging

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>: To stop debugging

While debugging, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to add a quick watch. Other debugging shortcuts can be found in the debug drop down menu.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
run to cursor when debugging. Looked for this for ages before I found the keyboard shortcut...

Answer (score 12):

If 'Favorite' is measured by how often I use it, then:

<kbd>F10</kbd> : Debug.StepOver

:)

Answer (score 12):

By usage, the pair:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>: insert blank line above the current line.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>: insert blank line below the current line.

Comment: CTRL + ENTER inserts above the current line on my VS2008.

Comment: Oops, I had them backwards. :o I don't even think about it anymore. :)

Comment: This is simple, but very useful.
It could save a lot of keystrokes, thank you.

Answer (score 12):

When the [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) drop down is displayed, holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> turns the list semi-transparent so you can see what is hidden behind it :)

Comment: If only I knew this before, I would have saved myself so much time and reliance on the Esc key :)

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>  -> Attach to process

Answer (score 11):

Haven't seen this one ...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>

Scrolls the window without moving the cursor.

Comment: It depends. On Visual Basic 2005 Express Edition (is a version of Visual Studio 2005 - 8.0.50727.42 (RTM 050727-4200)), it instead jumps to the previous/next subroutine (*Sub* or *Function*). It is still useful, though.

Answer (score 8):

Select word: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

I can't live without that shortcut.  Used over 100+ (or 200+) a day.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it selects up on hierarchy. For example, within a block if you press Ctrl+W, it first select the word near to, if you press Ctrl+W again, now it selects the surrounding block and so on.

Comment: In VS 2010 it's now been co-opted for multi-key window shortcuts.

Comment: @RandomEngy - not in my VS2010

Comment: Maybe it's only for C# development settings?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
Save all changed files. saved me quite a few times.

Answer (score 7):

Good old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for flipping back and forth between open documents.

Visual Studio actually provides a very nice <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> implementation; I especially appreciate that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> document activation order is most-recently-used order, rather than simple "left-to-right" order, so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (press once and release) can be used repeatedly to flip back and forth between the two most-recently-used documents, even when there are more than two documents open.

Comment: And dont forget you can arrow left in the popup to go to tool windows too....

Comment: Another way to do this is to use Alt+W+2. This is go back and forth.  Also allows for 3 way action using Alt+W+3, if you can remember the right order.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>**T**</kbd> (Runs the current test)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>**A**</kbd> (Runs all tests in the project)

Comment: I wish there were a way to pop up the test results panel...

Answer (score 7):

By far the most useful (after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>*,* <kbd>C</kbd> - to Comment out selection
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>*,* <kbd>U</kbd> - to Uncomment a selection

Comment: In VS 2008 selection is Ctrl+E C to comment and Ctrl+E U to uncomment.     I like them along with Ctrl+E D to reformat.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/99276#99276

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> Tools.RecordTemporaryMacro (again to stop recording)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Tools.RunTemporaryMacro

Beats the heck out of trying to work out a regexp search and replace!

Comment: I just disabled these. I hit record by mistake trying for show whitespace Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W. The macros bog everything down, and it takes me a while to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Surround with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>S</kbd>.

It is great when you want to wrap some text in a tag.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for incremental search

Comment: It's Ctrl+I not an "L": fixed

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/98846#98846

Answer (score 4):

I like my code clean and arranged so my favorite keyboard shortcuts are the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> - Format document

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> - Format selected code

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd> - Show white spaces

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Cut line

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - Insert line below

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> for incremental search.

Comment: @FooBar : What does it mean?  Incremental Search?

Comment: @odiseh : Incremental search is where you start typing, and the selection keeps jumping to the first match of whatever you've typed so far. It usually saves you keystrokes, since you can just start typing until you've found what you're looking for. It also doesn't pop up a dialog.

Answer (score 4):

In debug mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> jumps to the current breakpoint, where execution is stopped.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> = Exception/Catch Settings and code snippets

Answer (score 3):

I hate closing the extra tabs when I use "Start Debugging" on ASP.NET apps.  Instead, I usually use "Start without Debugging" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).
If I end up needing to debug, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Attach to Process) 
and choose WebDev.WebServer.exe.  Then I'm still on my previous page and I only have one tab open.

Comment: C-F5 is dup. Alt D P is alternative for Ctrl Alt P

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (Move to corresponding }) 
 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Cycle clipboard)

Answer (score 3):

The combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for finding selected and previous selected item works very well for me.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>F9</kbd>: toggle and un-toggle breakpoints!

Answer (score 3):

#### Cutting and pasting lines

Everyone knows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for cutting/copying text; but did you know that in VS you don't have to select the text first if you want to cut or copy a single line? If nothing is selected, the whole line will be cut or copied.

Comment: I'm floored by how many people don't know/use this. I'm also floored that the C# editor team still can't get the cursor placement correct.

Comment: Interesting, I actually didn't know that but always used the Shift+Del combination to do the same thing... which is prolly why I never noticed this way.

Answer (score 3):

#### Showing hidden windows

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> + Solution explorer
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> + Server explorer
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> + Output
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> + Toolbox
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> + Watch
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> + Error list
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> + Class view

I like to use all my screen real estate for code and have everything else hidden away. These shortcuts keep these windows handy when I need them, so they can be out of the way the rest of the time.

Comment: Or you could just remember one shortcut: Shift + Alt + Enter

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>  - Build the current project.

Comment: Or Shift F6 in the C# bindings

Comment: Technically speaking, I think this should be 'Alt, B, U'.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shows the syntax/overloads for the current function you are typing parameters for.

Answer (score 3):

Open a **newline above** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Open a **newline below** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're **really**

> always up for leaving my hands on the
>   keyboard and away from the mouse!

Than you should go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en)

It's not really my favorite, it's just everything!

A shortcut a day will keep the mouse away.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for 'Navigate To' window ([link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/21/searching-and-navigating-code-in-vs-2010-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

This causes the list of open files to pop open in the upper right corner of the editor window. The cool thing is that it is searchable so you can leave go of the keys and start typing the file name to shift the focus to that file. Very handy when you have zillions of files open.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - Build

Comment: -1: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/99126#99126 (Even if it breaks the 'one' request)

Answer (score 2):

There are some great tips and trips and shortcuts on [Sara Ford's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/default.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch between designer/code view

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> to stop a build. 
Great for those "oh, I realized this won't compile and I don't want to waste my time" moments.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> opens the resharper smart tag

***Bookmark ShortCuts***
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to place a bookmark
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to go to next bookmark
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to go to previous bookmark

***The refactor shortcuts***.
 Each starts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. 
Follow it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for rename. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for extract method. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for encapsulate field.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your keyboard settings set to the "Visual C# 2005" setting, the window switching and text editing chords are excellent. You hit the first combination of Ctrl + Key, then release and hit the next letter.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>: Comment Selected Text
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>: Uncomment Selected Text
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>: Show Error List
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>: Show Object Browser
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>: Show Solution Explorer
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>: Show Toolbox

I still use <kbd>F4</kbd> to show the properties pane so I don't know the chord for that one.

If you go to the Tools > Customise menu option and press the Keyboard button, it gives you a list of commands you can search to see if a shortcut is available, or you can select the "Press Shortcut Keys:" textbox and test shortcut keys you want to assign to see if they conflict.

**Addendum:** I just found another great one that I think I'll be using quite frequently: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> 
pops up an intellisense box asking you what you would like to surround the selected text with. It's exactly what I've needed all those times I've needed to wrap a block in a conditional or a try/catch.

Comment: That Ctrl+K, S is awesome!!!. Coupled with successive Ctrl+W and you have a winner for fast coding.

Answer (score 2):

#### Commenting

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Comment current item
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> - Uncomment current item

The great thing about this is that it applies to the element you're currently in - you don't have to select a whole line of VB code to comment it, for example, you just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment the current line. On an aspx page, you can comment out a big chunk of code - for example an entire ListView - by just going to the first line and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Some handy ones that I use often are:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> -> Forces Intellisence to pop up.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> -> Show the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl + BP</kbd> (Previous bookmark), <kbd>Ctrl + BN</kbd> (Next bookmark)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> for selecting the current word

Comment: it says this one is a chord...

Answer (score 2):

The combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for converting a block of characters to all upper/lower case.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**Ctrl** + **K** + **C**</kbd> - set current selected code to be comments
<kbd>**Ctrl** + **K** + **U**</kbd> - set current selected comments to be code

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> - Backtracks go to previous "<kbd>F12</kbd>/ Go to definition"

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + 7 is the complementary shortcut to do that - go fwd to next Go To Def invoked in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>*,* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> : collapse to definitions. I use it all the time together with #regions
 (despite [what Jeff says](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001147.html)) to get an overview of the code on my screen.

Comment: Me too!! I collapse to definitions, then drill down with Ctrl+M+M: Toggle Outlining Expansion

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> steps out of the current function. 
This is very useful when you want to debug function foo in foo(bar(baz()). Use <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to jump in and out of bar and baz.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Arrow keys(<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>) or mouse moving = Block/Column selection

comes really handy

Answer (score 1):

#### Find and replace

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Find, Find & replace, respectively
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Find in files, Find & replace in files, respectively

"Find in files" has been an enormous productivity booster for me. Rather than jump to each result one by one, it just shows you a list of results in your entire project or solution. It makes it very simple to find sample code, or see if a function is used anywhere.

Comment: And then F8/Shift-F8 to step the results

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F7</kbd> toggles from design view to code view.

Answer (score 1):

Not a keyboard shortcut, but with your mouse, you can use forward and backwards buttons on your mouse to go to previous locations in your code and return to your current location.

Comment: You must be using an add-in because stock Visual Studio doesn't do this. I actually wrote (and still use) an add-in that does this.

Comment: @280Z28: Works for me in VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com), which I highly recommend you do, these are useful:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>: Toggle current document between header/implementation (.h/.cpp)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>: Go to definition/declaration

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F7</kbd> to build and then <kbd>F8</kbd> to go to the errors and warnings one by one.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> ;)

But on a more serious note, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is probably hit a lot from me, in my limited usage of VS.

Comment: -1: Duplicate (even if this was first, the other is upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> Refactor with Resharper

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> : Format Document

**Tip for teams**: Set up agreed-on formatting options in Visual Studio (they are very flexible), then export the settings to a .settings file for each developer to import.

Now if all developers learn to autoformat everything, it will not only produce *perfect formatting consistency throughout the project with no effort at all*, but also greatly reduce annoying false differences in the diff tool when merging multiple check-ins to Source Control.

Oh, I enjoy good tools!

Comment: I see Sung Meister lists the same command, but with a different key combination. Myself, I use the Visual C# environment settings, I guess he doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Insert snippet:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

I use if often for `try..catch` and `#region`

Comment: I instead just type `try` or `#region` and then hit TAB, TAB.  

(But that might be helpful if you forget which snippets, such as for Dr. WPF's big list of property snippets for WPF: [link](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/17/my-wpf-code-snippets/))

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to open quickwatch while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> multiple times cycles through the clipboard ring.

Answer (score 1):

Control+Apostrophe.

Oh wait, that was *after* I remapped it away from that god-awkward Alt+Shift+F10 or whatever it was.

When you remap *options to help bind this* away from it's original hard to hit shortcut, it becomes a lot lot more useful.

Comment: Really? i *love* Alt-Shift-F10!

Comment: @RCIX - To clarify, I love what Alt+Shift+F10 does, but I don't love how hard it is to hit compared to Ctrl+Apostrophe.

Comment: Posting just the keys themselves is pointless.  Most (sensible) people don't know what Alt+Shift+F10 because they've always used Ctrl + .

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, but

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

deletes the entire line.  Great for fast code editing.

Answer (score 1):

I mapped all of the expand/collapse commands so that they can be used with the left and only so my right hand stays on my mouse.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> toggles expansion,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> collapses all to definitions, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> toggles all outlining.

Comment: Funny, I always prefer my hands to stay on the keyboard and try not to use the mouse. (The down-vote isn't mine, though.)

Comment: 99% of the time i keep my hands on the keyboard, too.  But there are times when I'm studying code that its convenient to have a hand on the mouse and being able to expand/collapse with just my left hand is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to display whitespace (great for tab or space enforcement).

Also, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting with the mouse will create a rectangular region.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to auto format code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Emacs-like keybinding, it's <kbd>TAB</kbd> :P

Answer (score 0):

What [Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts#98648) said. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

I really didn't like the smart tags (those little blue and red underscores that appear wanting to help you) until I found out that you don't need to waste time trying to hover the mouse over the exact pixel that gets the menu to show.

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to open the smart tag menu saves me about five minutes every day and reduces my blood pressure considerably.

Comment: I think default was "Alt+Shift+F10"...  Mine was overwritten by Resharper...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> // Save

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> // Build

Answer (score 0):

I have two that I use a lot, the first is standard, the second you have to map:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> (Select All, Format Selection)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> (Remove Unused Usings and Sort)

Both help pay down the "cruft debt" early and often

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to add a line of code to the built in task/todo list
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). Very handy!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

This cuts (to clipboard) the current line of code.

Comment: This "cuts" the line. Ctrl+ L for delete.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing beats <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - Building the solution!!

As far as navigation control, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is nice... 
But I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> ---> creates bookmark... 
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> ---> to navigate to the next bookmark... awesome stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Another useful Find short key sequence is
Ctrl (+ Shift) F --> ALT C --> ALT W for switching between exact and fuzzy searches.

Answer (score 0):

Save LOTS of time copy and cutting:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with no selection in the line: copies the whole line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> with no selection - cuts the whole line

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Format the current document.

Helped me fix indentation and remove unneeded spaces quickly

Answer (score 0):

"prop" and hit tab.. stubs out property for you...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>*,* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will expand every collapsed bit of code. It is the opposite of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>*,* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

#### Turn line wrapping on and off

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Sometimes you want to see the flow of the code with all of your indents in place; sometimes you need to see all 50  attributes in a GridView declaration. This lets you easily switch back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

#### Format document

```
   Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D
```

1. On an aspx page, this takes care of properly indenting all of your markup and ensures that everything is XHTML compliant (adds quotes to attributes, corrects capitalization, closes self-closing tags). I find that this makes it much easier to find mismatched tags and to make sure that my markup makes sense. If you don't like how  it's indenting, you can control which tags go on their own line and how much space they get around them under  **Tools/Options/Text Editor/HTML/Format/Tag Specific Options**.
2. In your C# or VB code, this will correct any  capitalization or formatting issues that didn't get caught automatically.
3. For CSS files, you can choose compact (one definition per line), semi-expanded, or expanded (each rule on its own line); and you can choose how it handles capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

#### Refresh javascript intellisense and code coloring.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

I've found intellisense for Javascript to be flaky - this usually straightens it out.

Answer (score 0):

#### Outlining

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - Collapse/expand current element
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Collapse all (gives you a nice overview of a complex class, for example)
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Toggle all

This works both in VB/C# code (e.g. collapse/expand a function) and in an aspx page (e.g. collapse/expand a GridView definition).

One very nice use of this is to cut or copy a big chunk of markup or code: For example, to move a big, sprawling `<table>` or `<asp:gridview>` definition:

1. Go to the first line
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to collapse it
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut it (you don't have to select it, as long as your insertion point is still in that line)
4. Move to where you want it and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

Answer (score 0):

#### Snippets

Each snippet has a shortcut that you can access by typing a word then tab. The one I use the most is for a standard property definition; just type **property** then tab.

Comment: On my VS2008 the default is prop{TAB}, not property.

Answer (score 0):

Open a file without using the mouse:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (opens command window)
Followed by >open somedoc

I didn't see this one yet.  Can't believe how many cool shortcuts have been posted here!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a [list](http://www.wwwcoder.com/Weblogs/tabid/283/EntryID/774/Default.aspx) of Shortcuts I find usefull (VS2003) but some still apply,

My favorite being <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to navigate to the declaration and back

Comment: ctrl +'-' goes back to the last line your cursor was on in my VS

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>
 Attach the debugger to the application.

(first letter of any application you want to debug, works most of the time)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (incremental seach)

Comment: Think these are all dups (and questioner asked for 1 per answer)

Answer (score 0):

Simple one. <kbd>F8</kbd> : Go to next build error.
Found that now it will work in any sort of list window (the ones that cluster together at the bottom usually.

Comment: e.g. the find in files results

Comment: and Shift F8 in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, nobody said <kbd>F1</kbd> for help. 
 
 Could it be that Google is faster and better for getting at the information that you need.

Comment: Hit F1, make a coffee, go to google, type in your query (one finger typing), fully read each search return on the first 3 1/2 pages, find your answer and fix the code, catch a train home, do the cryptic crossword, have a beer, sleep in, go to work and have a coffee, check your pc, and wait ...

Comment: There's nothing more frustrating than accidentally hitting F1

Comment: Perhaps F1 should just open a browser pointed at Google in a Visual Studio tab.  I love how Google is better at finding reference materials than most web site's own searches (and most application's built-in references in this case).

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> : *Format Code*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd> : *Collapse To Definitions*
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>   : *Undo* :)
4. <kbd>F9</kbd>: *Breakpoint*
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> : *Delete All Breakpoints*

Answer (score 0):

The ones I use all the time:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>  Matching Brace
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> Select to the end of brace
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> Untabify
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> comment out the currently selected block
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> uncomment out the currently selected block
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+mouse move vertical selection
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> toolbox
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> build

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close all windows. You have to map it yourself:

Instructions:

- In Visual Studio, go to Tool | Options
- Under Environment select Keyboard
- In Show commands containing, enter
  Window.CloseAllDocuments. You should
  get a single entry in the listbox
  below it
- Put the cursor in Press shortcut keys
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.
- Click OK

Credit to [Kyle Baley at codebetter.com](http://codebetter.com/blogs/kyle.baley/archive/2008/05/31/close-everything-and-unzip-all.aspx).  I modified his example to use shift instead of alt because it was easier on my hands.

Comment: I bind this to Ctrl+W (close window) and Ctrl+Shift+W (close all windows) to match several other programs.

Answer (score 0):

I've mapped File.Close to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. That and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> mean you can close exactly whichever files you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my favourite debugging keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>F5</kbd> : start debugger / run to next breakpoint
- <kbd>Shift+F5</kbd> : stop debugging
- <kbd>F10</kbd> : step over next statement
- <kbd>F11</kbd> : step into next statement
- <kbd>Ctrl+F10</kbd>: run to the cursor location
- <kbd>F9</kbd> : add or remove breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I'm addicted to some very subtle stuff in http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/UsefulVSKeySequencesShortcuts.aspx

e.g. <kbd>Alt-W U</kbd> to auto collapse everything when in Full screen mode when it all gets too much

Answer (score 0):

Paste in loop <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + V</kbd>

Expand Collapse current block - <kbd>Ctrl + M + M</kbd>

Code Snippet - for creating property type prop and press <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> - Expands all regions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any shortcut is remaining for me to mention so let me mention a shortcut that I would love Visual Studio to have :-)
One shortcut that I really miss and that is present in Eclipse is "Open Resource" (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + S</kbd>) which allows you to type in a file name and the IDE displays the files matching it. Really useful when you are working with bid code bases!

Comment: See [Ctrl+/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/1441130#1441130).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

Select all, [prettyprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint).

Answer (score 0):

People have mentioned Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to paste a line when nothing is selected but I use Ctrl+X to move lines of code regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this hasn't already been posted, apologies if so. I've just come across a useful keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2008. With the QuickWatch window open, highlight a row with a string value in it and hit <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>. The text visualiser window will appear with the value in it.

I have found it quite useful for checking jQuery innerText values as the QuickWatch window by default is too small to show longer strings fully.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
Rebuild Solution.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
Debug Tests in Current Context

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised not to find this one on the list as I use it all the time:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> - Implement method stub.

Write a call to a non-existent method, and then use that shortcut to create the method in the right place, with the right parameters and return value, but with a method body that just throws a NotImplementedException.

Great for top-down coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is definitely my favourite. I use it more than any other shortcuts. It helps to format the document according to the indentation and code formatting settings specified by us.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

To include a missing library.

Comment: Looks like you don't use Resharper don't you.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. But if you are a keyboard lover then go for Resharper

Comment: It doesn't even state what do actually do...