# What are your most frequently used shortcut keys in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Recently , I found some shortcut key really helpful which I never used before .
Such keys like <kbd>F7</kbd> ,<kbd>F3</kbd> ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> help me a lot when editing and debuging.
What are your most frequently used shortcut keys in visual studio?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> for bringing up the smart tag for adding namespaces, renaming/refactoring, etc.

I also remapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to build, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to Build Selection (in a sense, Build Project) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close window.

Comment: how do you remap shortcuts in VS?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out: Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard

Answer (score 15):

including Resharper's shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> (build)
- <kbd>F12</kbd> (go to definition)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> (find usages)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> (go to last location)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> (go to current file in the solution explorer)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> (find member)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> (find type)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> (find file)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> (close current dialog)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> (save all files - VS tends to forget)

EDIT: added explanations

Comment: How about including what each of those do next to them?

Comment: which keys are used to collapse all projects in vs 2008 solutuion

Answer (score 12):

I always use the debugging keyboard shortcuts - <kbd>F9</kbd> (toggle breakpoint), <kbd>F10</kbd> (step over) and <kbd>F11</kbd> (step into). I can't believe that some of my coworkers actually use the toolbar buttons for this - it's insanely more efficient to use the shortcuts.

Comment: + also Shift-F11 to step out of the current routine, and Shift-F5 to cancel execution.

Answer (score 5):

Standard VS keys of <kbd>F12</kbd> for going to the definition and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to go back to where I was before that.

Probably the two shortcuts that get me around VS and my code quicker than any other.

Answer (score 2):

The most used keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabs.

Another one I use alot is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to start incremental search.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for comment selection and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for uncomment selection (They may be mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in some standard keyboard mappings, but the first two will generally still work...)

Answer (score 2):

Two more:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for Call Stack
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for Immidiate window

(Both helpful while debugging)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then ">of $filename" (open filename),

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (comment selection),

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (format),

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on a line to cut

or copy the entire line

Comment: See also http://www.chinhdo.com/20070920/top-11-visual-studio-2005-ide-tips-and-tricks-to-make-you-a-more-productive-developer/

Answer (score 1):

The list is endless.  To maximize readble code space, I've removed all my toolbars.  If I want to do it, I have to know the keyboard shortcut for it.

Aside from the basics, I constantly use things like <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-P</kbd>.  I have also made a little smiley-face button for "Remove and Sort Usings" because navigating through the right-click menu takes too long and it doesn't have a hotkey that I know of.

Comment: You can run Visual Studio in fullscreen mode as well! I've hooked it up to F11.

Comment: You could always map a keyboard shortcut to Remove and Sort usings

Comment: ALT e i o a... that navigates through the menu's via your keys to get to the Remove and Sort menu item. It's very quick to type. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I use many, but most useful I think is 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>for setting a bookmark
and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> for going to next bookmark and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> for previous

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to build current project, <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>F5</kbd> to stop debugging

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to delete all the break points in a solution. Very handy when people leave them spattered all over the solution!

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-B to view the list and then you can selectively disble thme either

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
which for me is build current project.
I use it less in VS2008 SP1 with the error highlighting so
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
which for me is Go To Definition is starting to edge it out.

Answer (score 0):

I never can remember shortcuts, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>-</kbd> . is one of the few I can remember and use often.  With Resharper installed, <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> . on steroids.  Both intelligently resolve a variety of errors or refactorings.

Answer (score 0):

I use the bookmark shortcuts alot: <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> to create a bookmark, <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> to cycle through them.

<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-B</kbd> to build is probably the most executed though.