# "in-line find" plug-in for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, search, ide, plugins, add-in

Is there a plug-in (or built-in feature) for Visual Studio 2008 to be able to do a quick in-line find in your code?

I am unhappy with the find feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). I don't like how it pops up in its own window. I think it would be much better if it was more like the Firefox find. (Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Firefox). I like how you start typing and it instantly tries to match what you're typing. Often you don't have to type your full search term before you find what you want.

I am use to FlashDevelop, and think they have good some great search functionality. you can just selected a word in your code and tap <kbd>F3</kbd>. It will instantly select the next occurrence of that string.

So is there anything out there with this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.  This is the "inline find" version you want.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> will start a search for the word that the caret is in (without displaying the Find dialog).  Subsequent presses of <kbd>F3</kbd> will continue the search forward.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> will search backwards.  The whole word and case sensitive options of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> Find dialog are used during <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You already got your answer from 1800 INFORMATION, but I figured you might find this one interesting as well:

> [Favorite Visual Studio keyboard
> shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts)

A good amount of Visual Studio keyboard goodness.

Comment: Thanks for that link. very nice!