# Visual Studio Format entire file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, formatting, coderush-xpress

Is there a way to issue a key command to properly format an entire file in VS2008 with CodeRush Express?

Comment: When you select Edit->Advanced from menu what keystrokes do you see for Format Document?

Comment: Or if you need to do it automatically, the .NET foundation released their code formatting tool on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to format document keystroke

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format selection keystroke

It's also possible to set your own keystrokes by opening Options... dialog (select Tools->Options from the menu).  In Options dialog select Environment->Keyboard form the tree and set your own shortcuts for Edit.FormatDocument.

Comment: That is, press "Ctrl+K", release it, and then press "Ctrl+D".

Comment: @RCIX When you select Edit->Advanced from menu what keystrokes do you see for Format Document?

Comment: And on top of that when i use snippets (like pressing tab twice after typing if) i get all screwed up indenting, and osme CR refactorings get that too

Comment: This looks more like CodeRush problem to me.

Comment: It should be noted that Ctrl+K, D is a VS shortcut, and not a CodeRush command

Comment: This doesn't work on Visual Studio 2019 for me. Tried both combinations, nothing happened.

Answer (score 9):

You could always go to *Tools -> Options -> Keyboard* and give the **Edit.FormatDocument** a new shortcut.

**Update** You can also see what the Shortcuts mapped to this command are this way.

Comment: It looks like mentioned about Edit.FormatDocment before last edit of my question.  I honestly didn't see your answer.  But you definitely deserve +1 but being first.

Comment: I was just giving you a hard time, no worries

Comment: There is no `Options` in the Tools menu on VS Community for Mac.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[This question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts) has a lot of handy tips.

Answer (score 2):

Shortcut in visual studio to format the whole document is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Just select all content of page by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.
The whole page tag format.

For example see this link:
[Format the content](http://blog.weonix.com/Posts/Details/4#comments)

Answer (score 2):

If  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>  **or** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't work for you, try to set below settings:
`Tools->Options -> Text Editor ->C# ->Tabs`,
 make sure `Keep tabs is selected.
Then, go back to your text editor, re-try formatting.

I was really annoyed before, and steps above works for me. hope it works for you guys..

Answer (score 0):

I just use built-in Visual Studio formatting command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Visual Studio Express 2013.