# Is there a free tool/plugin that can format code ect on the fly for VS C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, code-formatting

Ive just moved from VB.Net to C#. I dont understand why people are using it/prefer it as it is soo much more time consuming!

In VB.NET, you simply type your code and VB.NET formats is as you go, For example:

removes unneccessary whitespace,
automatically puts in brackets,
tabs blocks of code,
automatically creates the NEXT, END IF, statements for blocks.

and the opposite/nuiances in C#
if you change the name of an event handler it creates a new one, doesnt rename the existing one
you must have the () at the end of a method

and im sure theres more.

Why is C# backwards like this? Surely there must be a way to improve productivity somehow. Any ideas or free tools out there?

Comment: If you use Refactor > Rename all the instance of that name are changed.

Comment: Good comments, thanks. Should help some of the issues im experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not automatic BUT.....

> Use
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
>   to format document keystroke
>
> Use
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
>   to format selection keystroke

From [Visual Studio Format entire file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435691/visual-studio-format-entire-file/1435702#1435702)

Comment: thanks for the keystroke combo. Does what i need... now if there was only some way to set up a timer...

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the language, and everything to do with the *editor*.

Regardless, the editor for C# in visual studio does support automatic formatting in several ways.

If you delete and reinsert the closing brace `}`, it will reformat/reindent automatically.

There are several menu items and corresponding keyboard shortcuts that will reformat code for you:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> - this will reformat the whole document.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> - this will reformat the selection.

There are also extensive refactoring capabilities - the rename refactoring will rename a member everywhere it is mentioned, even if it is in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2008 and it behaves exactly as you describe. Pretty much every time I type a semi-colon or curly brace, it corrects all formatting within the context.

For example...

```
if     (myValue!= null) {
someValue = myValue;
```

If I type the closing curly brace, it turns into this:

```
if (myValue != null) 
{
    someValue = myValue;
}
```

All dependent on the style settings in Tools > Options

Answer (score 1):

Also there exits some so called *code snippets*. If you simply type `if` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> this will automatically result into

```
if (true)
{
}
```

setting the cursor directly onto the `true`.

Even better is the `switch` snippet. If you enter switch and press the <kbd>tab</kbd> twice you'll get

```
switch (switch_on)
{
    default:
}
```

where your cursor stands on `switch_on`.
If you now enter something meaningful like a variable name that holds an enum value (e.g. `var color = Color.Red;`) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will automatically fill in all possible cases.

There are [more code snippets](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/cheatsheets/visual-studio-2008-csharp-snippets.htm) available and some are very handy like `foreach`, `try`, `prop`, `propg`.