# Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, curly-braces

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2008 to go from a closing brace to its opening brace?  I've found a fair amount of stuff about highlighting the brace, but nothing about moving the cursor to it.

(VB.NET version of this Question: [Keyboard shortcut for Jumping between "If/End If"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7888108/740639))

Comment: incredibly, this seems to not work (2019) for .js files on Mac Visual Studio. WTH ?!

Comment: @Fattie, It doesn't work in Windows 10 for .cs files either. I am pretty confident this is an across-the-board thing for VS 2019 so I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59183422/1739000

Comment: Instead of trying to CTRL+F this page for whatever language keyboard you are using, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309463) to figure it out in Visual Studio settings.

Comment: Since you might be here about VS Code, here is the question for that instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097634/how-do-i-jump-to-a-closing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: here's a little nit that's been driving me nuts. if you go to a matching brace in c++ and it's above your current position, it will put the carat on the matching brace and it will be the first line on the screen, you then have to arrow up to see what it's a brace for. is there any way to have to match and be a few lines down or in the middle of the screen? I know it's an edge case, but I run into this constantly.

Answer (score 818, accepted):

I found this for you: [Jump between braces in Visual Studio](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2008/07/09/jump-between-braces-in-visual-studio/):

> Put your cursor before or after the brace (your choice) and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. It works with parentheses ( ), brackets [ ] and braces { }.  From now on you don’t need to play Where’s Waldo? to find that brace.

With the above shortcut, you can also hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select.

On MacOS, use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> .

Comment: Just for information, on a Norwegian keyboard the short-cut for this is `Ctrl`+`Å` (same as for Danish keyboard mentioned in an answer below).

Comment: On Belgian azerty it seems to be `ctrl`+`^`, which is, oddly, on the key which also has the `[` bracket (which needs `AltGr` to be typed).

Comment: Icelandic keyboard CTRL + Ð

Comment: For Czech QWERTZ keyboard it's CTRL + ). 
Exactly same position, where English keyboard has ] key. Just above Enter.

Comment: @Ian The main answer applies to British keyboards, CTRL + ]

Comment: If you're working in a `.sql` file, `CTRL` + `]` will toggle between `BEGIN` and `END` pairs. (VS 2015)

Comment: Brazilian portuguese `abnt-2` keyboard: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `]`. There is no shortcut for "select to bracket" by default.

Comment: In my Dvorak keyboard mapping on my Mac, this turned out to be CTRL + =, which is bound to ] in the Dvorak mapping.

Comment: otherwise there is an extension that add the support for " and ' too https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chunsen.bracket-select with a simple shorcut alt+ a, for mac it is better because it selects whileCMD + SHIFT + \ don't select

Comment: I wasn't able to find the shortcut combination in Mac, at the end I use: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `CMD` + `LEFT ARROW` or `RIGHT ARROW` after the bracket `{`

Comment: German keyboard: `Strg` + `´`

Comment: Swiss German Keyboard : `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `à` or with "Atom Keymap" extension : `Ctrl` + `M`

Answer (score 124):

I use [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008), and you can customize what you want this shortcut to be.

Click menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Environment* -> *Keyboard*. Then look for **Edit.GotoBrace**.

This will tell you what key combination is currently assigned for this. I **think** you can change this if you want, but it's useful if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: This is very useful to find keybindings for other languages' keyboards.

Comment: Yes, we should always respond to command questions with the command name in case the keyboard is different or the default shortcut has been removed. Also check out Edit.GotoBraceExtend, if you map Ctrl+[something] to Edit.GotoBrace, you'll probably want to map Ctrl+Shift+[something] to Edit.GotoBraceExtend.

Comment: This was useful for me because it wasn't set for me at all in VS 2017.

Answer (score 116):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to switch between them. Place the cursor at one of the braces when using it.

Answer (score 26):

Note: It also works for #if / #elif / #endif matching. The caret must be on the <kbd>#</kbd>.

Answer (score 26):

If for some reason this is NOT working for you, something may have messed up your keyboard bindings (it didn't work for me).  You can re-enable the binding easy enough though - at least so I thought:

I tried this procedure:

- Go to menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Environment* -> *Keyboard*
- Scroll to, or search for the command Edit.GotoBrace
- Assign the desired shortcut (mine was empty, so I put in <kbd>CTRL</kbd>    + <kbd>]</kbd>)
- Be sure to click the "Assign Button"

I tried it, and it still didn't work. I restarted Visual Studio, and it still didn't work - well it ONLY worked for .cs files, but I need it to work for .vb files and text files, and...well ALL files!

Comment: For VB files, use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `UP/DOWN` (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895072/740639)

Answer (score 22):

On my French keyboard, it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks it works but where did you found it ? In my french version of Visual Studio, I did not found any equivalent to Edit.GotoBrace in Outils -> Options -> Environnement -> Clavier (proposed by other answers).

Answer (score 20):

On a German keyboard it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>.

Comment: For me this works on a German keyboard:
1. `Strg`+`´` : hightlights a span included by parentheses/braces/brackets.
2. `Left` or `Right` arrow key to jump to the begin or end of the highlighted span (and turns of the highlighting).

Answer (score 14):

On a Spanish keyboard it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>¿</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>¡</kbd>).

Comment: 10 minutes to discover WTF was ¡, as written into VS2008 options menu. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

On my Danish keyboard it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Å</kbd>.

Answer (score 13):

On a Turkish keyboard, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd>.

Answer (score 13):

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> will select all of the text.

Answer (score 11):

For completeness sake, on a Swedish keyboard it's  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>å</kbd> .

Also, I guess logical, but worth mentioning  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>å</kbd>  (for capital Å), selects everything inside the braces and goes to the matching one.

Answer (score 10):

On my Portuguese keyboard and SO with EN VS, it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>«</kbd> to navigate to matching brace and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>«</kbd> if you intend to select the inner code.

Answer (score 10):

On my Italian keyboard, it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

On my **pt-BR** (Brazilian Portuguese) keyboard it is actually <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

On my Slovenian keyboard it is <kbd>ALT</kbd>    + <kbd>Đ</kbd>

Comment: It's CTRL + đ by default

Answer (score 7):

For Visual Studio Code (as seen in [their documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_bracket-matching)), use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

The setting can be found in:

> File/Preferences/Keyboard Shortcut

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.8.0 . Note Visual Studio Code may behave differently for international keyboards (as seen in [this answer re: German keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532853/1175496))

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Note: this is for Visual Studio __Code__. The question is about Visual Studio. There is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097634/how-do-i-jump-to-a-closing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code) for VS Code.

Answer (score 7):

On a Mac use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

**Source**: a comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37877082/3345085.
Tested in Visual Studio Code version 1.10.2.

Comment: Note: this is for Visual Studio __Code__. The question is about Visual Studio. There is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097634/how-do-i-jump-to-a-closing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code) for VS Code.

Answer (score 6):

On my Dutch (Belgian) keyboard, it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Goto Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors, select the "Brace Matching (Rectangle)" and change the "Item Background" to e.g. Yellow. This worked for the C# parentheses () {} and [].

Comment: Yes helpful & 'Display Name' text box of Fonts & Colors is where Brace Matching Rectangle is located.

Comment: If you have the dark theme like I do, cyan instead of yellow will also make the bracket itself more visible.

Answer (score 6):

## Details that can benefit everyone (Linux/Win/Mac)

The command in the keyboard shortcuts menu/editor is `editor.action.jumpToBracket` there you can set it to whatever you like. There is also one called `editor.action.selectToBracket` which has no shortcut by default (at least on Mac).

## Etc.

On the Mac `editor.action.jumpToBracket` starts out as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>
 and I changed it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to be in line with what others say here. I did so in the hopes that I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to "Extend selection to matching bracket". That is what lead me to discover the details above. I set `editor.action.selectToBracket` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and got exactly the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

On a Hungarian keyboard it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ú</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

A bit relevant, but for HTML tags: (since there is no built-in solution, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> doesn't work for HTML tags : )

Here is the answer as a macro which I've built which does it (toggle), including go to focus:

Here is the demo:

[image]

And here is the code. Enjoy!

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module Module2
    Sub beginToEnd()

        'Place the cursor somewhere in the beginning tag, run the macro, to select from beginning to end tag

        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim objSel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim topPoint As TextPoint = objSel.TopPoint
        Dim lTopLine As Long = topPoint.Line
        objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine, False)
        '  DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line1 As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text()

        If InStr(line1, "/") Then

            ' MsgBox(line1)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText, True)
            objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine, False)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
        Else
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(False)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
        End If

        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line2 As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text()
        Dim objSel3 As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim topPoint3 As TextPoint = objSel3.TopPoint
        Dim lTopLine3 As Long = topPoint3.Line
        objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine3, False)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText, False)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The standard US mapping of <Control> + ], works for me in HTML and CSS as well.
Both tags get highlighted too.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio Code on german keyboard it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>

But you have to open a file with correct extension - it's not working in new unsaved files for example.

Comment: Note: this is for Visual Studio __Code__. The question is about Visual Studio. There is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097634/how-do-i-jump-to-a-closing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code) for VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

On the Swiss-French keyboard : use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

On Spanish (Spain) keyboard with VS2012 is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¡</kbd> as stated by @Keith but if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¿</kbd> (typed as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>¡</kbd>) then goes to Matching Brace plus selects all the code within the two braces and then you can't go again to the other brace.

Answer (score 0):

June 2021

On a Mac running Windows 10 under parallels for Visual Studio 2019 and c# and with US keyboard the solution which worked for me was to edit the shortcut in"
Tools
Options
Keyboard
Edit.GoToBrace

On my system that shortcut was blank...

Press the Ctl key and the ] key and save the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Windows, Visual Studio 2017, C++, Hungarian keyboard, Ctrl+ú

In `Options/Environment/Keyboard`, check `Editor.GotoBrace`.