# How to jump to Next statement from For or For Each (like braces but in vb) in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, for-loop, braces

Does anyone know what the keyboard shortcut for jumping from the start of a keyword, such as `for`, `forEach`, `if`, `while` etc... is in Visual Studio when your using **"vb.net"**? I found the following **[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)**, which I thought would do what I was looking for, but it doesn't.

Following a comment from the linked question above, I checked the path:

- **`Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard`**

...for the **`Edit.GotoBrace`** command. From what I read, the command should be mapped to the keybinding: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>å</kbd>** in Swedish.

`Vb.net` doesn't use braces per se, but in the following example:

```
  For Each Foo in Bar
    Do lots of stuff
  Next
```

I would have thought that the same command should jump me from the `For Each` to the "Next" but it doesn't do anything.  Is there another command (or should that command work but something is broken locally?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the sake of other SO users, and so the answer isn't buried as a comment inside of an answer:

> "...there are keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Shift+Up and Ctrl+Shift+Down) that move the editor caret
>   between highlighted references/keywords."

from:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534430/block-navigation-for-vb-net-similar-to-paranthesis-navigation

Comment: Wow, where has this been for the last 25 years?!   Love it.  At last!

Answer (score 2):

No can do.  It is a much harder task than matching braces.  Finding the matching NEXT keyword requires syntax parsing.  Braces can be matched by merely tokenizing the text.  I'd recommend you put in a feature request at connect.microsoft.com, it is a good request.

Comment: I've put in the request (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534430/block-navigation-for-vb-net-similar-to-paranthesis-navigation).  I wouldn't have thought it so very difficult - the background compiler already keeps track of them and shows an error if there is an unmatched For/Next.  In pure vb.net files VS does a pretty good job of indenting based on them too - but in .aspx/.ascx files it doesn't keep up with that so well.

Comment: I have now had a reply from Microsoft which indicates a partial solution should exist in VS2010 (see URL in previous comment)