# Keyboard shortcut for Jumping between "If/End If"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I know it's simple to do in C#, but what is the command to jump between If/End If marks in VB.Net like you can jump between braces in C#?

(C#-version of this Question: [Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1501921/2009))

Comment: Hans, but the IDE knows the other parts of the block, since it highlights it when selecting one of them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to jump between highlighted references and keywords.

Since these are `If` blocks, the IDE will highlight the `Then` keyword as well, so just tap Up/Down twice in rapid succession. Up/down wraps, so if you really want to save a keypress, hit the key in the "wrong" direction to get where you want.

Comment: Don't know if you could call it "brace matching" but it sure as heck gets the job done! Thanks!

Comment: what about visual studio 2008 ?

Comment: Yeah, that won't help you here. I'm not sure what will help you here.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Hi Jason . Can you please help me to sort it out with vs 2008 .

Comment: As I already said, I have no idea. Resharper or similar plugins may have a command, not sure. You should create a new question here for that.

Comment: Just a tip: if you were also looking to be able to find the end of a Select statement, it doesn't go from the Select to the End, it goes through each Case, so do a <Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Up> once and it wraps around to the end!

Comment: I found that I had to enable this : Tools->Options->Text Editor->Basic->Advanced->Highlight related keywords under cursor.

Comment: Also, ctrl+shift+up/down hops around in all other flow constructs besides IF/END IF: ie. Do, Select, et al

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to putting the opening curly-bracket in a comment just after the THEN and a matching closing curly-bracket in a comment before the EndIf.  This is a ghetto way of allowing VI to match the start/end of the block using % keystroke.

A more elegant way would be to use some sort of IDE that understands the block concept in the language you are editing.  Sometimes this feature is called a "folding editor" as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding_editor

Answer (score 0):

As I saw `else` marked when my caret stood at an `if` (in PHP code), 
 https://google.com/search?q=jump+between+if+and+else+in+vscode brought me here, 
 and patching together various hints led me to the following commands, 
 bound in ***Visual Studio* Code** aka **VSCode**

@ **Command Palette** (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> @ macOS)
`Go to Previous Symbol Highlight`
`Go to Next Symbol Highlight`

Reverse engineered default <kbd>F7</kbd> / <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> @ `keybindings.json`:

```
    {
        "key": "f7",
        "command": "editor.action.wordHighlight.next",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && hasWordHighlights"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+f7",
        "command": "editor.action.wordHighlight.prev",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && hasWordHighlights"
    },
```

To fit the right hand over a numpad keyboard, 
 and having a lot of combinations bound to other commands, 
 my `keybindings.json` (syntax is `.jsonc` - *JSON with Comments*) adds:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+numpad_subtract",
        "command": "editor.action.wordHighlight.prev" // "Go to Previous Symbol Highlight"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+numpad_add",
        "command": "editor.action.wordHighlight.next" // "Go to Next Symbol Highlight"
    },
```