# To find ending of a if { visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)

"if" will have starting { and ending }
how can we jump to the closing } of a if statement from starting { of the if.
What is the sort cut for the same in visual studio 2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio

Comment: nicolas  u r greate. ctrl+] do this