# Go to closing Tag in Visual studio (using Resharper)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-8.1

*I'm using the latest Resharper (v 8.1) with visual studio 2010.*

Is there a keyboard shortcut/feature to "Jump to closing tag"  ?

For example : if the cursor is on the first `tr` :

[image]

I want the cursor to go to the closing `tr`  which is `</tr>`

Is there any shortcut for this ?

*(p.s. - something like [goto matchine brace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio) but for Xml/html tags)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the answer  as macro which i've built which does it (toggle ) including go to focus :

Here is the demo :

[image]

And here is the code  , enjoy !

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module Module2
    Sub beginToEnd()

        'Place cursor somewhere in beginning tag, run macro, to select from beginning to End Tag

        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim objSel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim topPoint As TextPoint = objSel.TopPoint
        Dim lTopLine As Long = topPoint.Line
        objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine, False)
        '  DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line1 As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text()
        If InStr(line1, "/") Then

            ' MsgBox(line1)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText, True)
            objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine, False)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")


        Else

            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(False)
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")

        End If
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line2 As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text()
        Dim objSel3 As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim topPoint3 As TextPoint = objSel3.TopPoint
        Dim lTopLine3 As Long = topPoint3.Line
        objSel.GotoLine(lTopLine3, False)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstText, False)


    End Sub



End Module
```

Answer (score 6):

From what I've gathered there's no shortcut for this in either reSharper or Visual Studio. A "work around" would be to collapse the tag using Ctrl + M + M, then go to the start or end of the line using Home or End key. When you open it again using Ctrl + M + M will you be either at the top or bottom of the tag.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
- <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> (Depending if you want to go to the start or end tag)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

I heard that `ctrl + ]` does the trick

Comment: No. if  the cursor is `<<here>body> aaaaaa     </body>` and you press `ctrl]` it will take you  `<body<here>> aaaaaa     </body>` and not `<body> aaaaaa     <<here>/body>` as desired

Comment: @RoyiNamir +1 for your efforts in comments :)

Comment: Yeah Ctrl + ] brings you to the closing brace, not the closing tag. I posted another method you could use.