# How to jump to closing brace in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a shortcut to jump outside of a code block, right after a closing brace `}` of a current code block?

Let me explain.

Let's say there's a method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (enableCheckbox.Checked == true)
    {
        if (labelToChange.Text == "Right")
        {
            labelToChange.Text = "Left";
        }
        else
        {
            labelToChange.Text = "Right";
        }
    }
}
```

And my cursor is somewhere on the line `labelToChange.Text = "Left";`.

I would like to make it to jump to the closing brace `}` of current `if (labelToChange.Text == "Right")` code block by pressing `Ctrl+]`.

Then if I press `Ctrl+]` again, I would like it to jump to closing brace `}` of `if (enableCheckbox.Checked == true)` code block.

And then if Press `Ctrl+]` for the third time in a row, I would like to jump to the closing brace `}` of a code block of a method `private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in motion:
[image]

I was managed to achieve this behavior in WebStorm and PhpStorm by using a macro:
[image]

It goes to the end of code block and then it goes to the end of the line, so it stops outside of closing brace.

Comes very handy all the time when I am working with multiple code blocks: if/else, writing methods, anything, I use it all the time in WebStorm and PhpStorm.

Is there a way to achieve this in Visual Studio?

I know about default `Ctrl+]` shortcut, the problem with `Edit.GoToBrace` command is that it goes to the closing brace `}` only when cursor is at the opening brace `{` but not when cursor is anywhere else inside the code block.

PS Yes, I did check similar threads:

- [Go to closing Tag in Visual studio (using Resharper)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592855/go-to-closing-tag-in-visual-studio-using-resharper)
- [Jump to closing bracket in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097634/jump-to-closing-bracket-in-visual-studio-code)
- [Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)
- [move out of closing brace in visual studio shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956031/move-out-of-closing-brace-in-visual-studio-shortcut)

None of them help me to find a solution to my problem. Please help. [image]

Comment: `ctrl+}` to jump closing and opening braces

Comment: I know about default `Ctrl+]` shortcut, the problem with `Edit.GoToBrace` command is that it goes to the closing brace `}` only when cursor is at the opening brace `{` but not when cursor is anywhere else inside the code block.

Comment: Submitted a feature request if anyone is interested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-467830

Comment: great I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

## Update

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200926/4100915).

I am using VS2017, and had tested default shortcut keys: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, it can jump to the head of containing block.
This default shortcut is for `EditorContextMenus.Navigate.GoToContainingBlock`.
It works for me.

It is still working in VS2019

---

I found an extension for visual studio to achieve the enhanced "Edit.GotoBrace" command.

Please check it out.
Here's [FeinBrace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FeinSoftware.FeinBrace&ssr=false#overview)!

I have tested in my IDE(visual studio 2017).
It works in

1. Goto Start of Block ( Alt+[, [ )
2. Goto End of Block ( Alt+], ] )

other functions are not working.

And the extension has been not updated for a while.  There are more related extension for visual studio code. But I don't know is it suitable for visual studio.

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.

Comment: @JaimilPatel thanks for your kind reminder. I will post more explanation and experience.

Comment: Works but only up until 2015 version. I'm using 2019 version.

Comment: Unfortunately, when used at function level, EditorContextMenus.Navigate.GoToContainingBlock goes to the start of the function, not the start of the function's code block (i.e. it doesn't put the cursor on the opening brace.  That means you can't turn around and use Ctrl+] to jump to the end of the function.