# Select everything between matching brackets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there in VS Code a shortcut available which selects all code between matching brackets? E.g. in Atom, this shortcut is `ctrl+alt+m`.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Place the cursor inside the bracket (not directly next to a bracket) and execute `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` until everything inside the bracket is selected. The default shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> on Mac).

You can shrink the selection with `editor.action.smartSelect.shrink` which has the default shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> on Mac).

Comment: Sometime it didn't work, shrink never work also. Is it a bug of VSCode

Comment: I'm using VSC 1.8.1 and this works by pressing `shift` + `alt` + `right`(this last key must be pressed 3 times).

Comment: Looks like this doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: The default as of 1.19.2 is `ctrl+shift+cmd+right` to grown and `...-left` to shrink. Just search the Keyboard Shortcuts menu for "smartselect" and the two commands and their current setting will be highlighted.

Comment: @AhmedFasih This shortcut works, but not when you are in multi-select mode (Cmd+D)... It only selects the content on the first line :(

Comment: Also, since this shortcut is super impractical I remaped it to `cmd+'` and `cmd+;`. Much better

Comment: Can we achieve this using mouse click? In eclipse, I was able to do a double click with the scope of a brackets and the entire code snippet use to get selected within that brackets

Comment: Wonderful shortcut, though it's unclear how to make the cursor end up in the start of selection, so I may continue to select a couple of rows on top, like comments & such

Comment: Does not work for me... I am using VSCode 1.70 and I hit F1 and type 'smart' and it says "No matching commands".

Comment: Nice! this little trick is such a timesaver!

Answer (score 27):

I still think [the expand region extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region) is the way to go on this.  But vscode 1.20 did add the "Select to Bracket" command (see command palette).  It has no default keybinding but the command is

```
editor.action.selectToBracket
```

so you can assign your own binding.   But it is not as handy as the extension.  The smartSelect options mentioned above give me unexpected/unwanted results.

----------   **Update**  ---------------

`editor.action.smartSelect.expand` command was added at some point after the answers here.

Bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>.  Will progressively expand the selection including to within and not including the brackets, parentheses if you wish.  You will need to keep triggering the <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> to get to where you want.  Will not select only within the brackets if you start right next to a bracket - start anywhere else and it will.

Comment: Is it possible to modify editor.action.selectToBracket in order for it to select between parentheses? It is currently working for both "{}" and "[]", but not "()"

Comment: @Stenemo any update being able to select up to brackets and parenthesis?

Comment: @ SantoshGupta7 and @Stenemo : See the additional info I added to the end of the answer about selecting between and not including brackets.

Answer (score 17):

I suggest to remap those keys to another key, this key combination is popular, sometimes it doesn't work because of the conflict with other apps.

Open the key binding setting, type the `smartselect` to find this setting, grow is expand the selection from the cursor current position to the nearest bracket, press multiple times if you want to expand or shrink to the next bracket.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks great, but it doesnt work for me! Any ideas?

Comment: In current version (1.55.2) the default `smartselect` is `^-shift-right`

Answer (score 14):

As answered by Mark, `editor.action.selectToBracket` works. I assigned keybindings to

***<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>***

as keyboard shortcut. This used to be default in Older version of VS.

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> is shortcut for "Go to bracket"

Comment: Why does it select the bracket?

Comment: how to except the bracket?

Answer (score 9):

In MacOS: it's `shift + control + right`, you hit right a few time to expand the `smartSelect`.

- To find your own settings related to `smartSelect`, go to `Keyboard Shortcuts` or use `command + k command + s`.
- You can check VSCode `Keyboard Shortcuts Reference` by typing `command + k command + r`. It will lead you to [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

I am using this extension, called [Quick and Simple Text Selection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select) - yes, that's the name :)

If you don't want to use an extension, this is the best I come up with so far: go to `edit keyboard shortcuts` and from there open your `keybindings.json` file and add the following lines

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+'",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend this extension

Comment: I also use a combination of `Alt + Shift + Right / Left` and Quick and Simple Text Selection. I love the extension's meaningful shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer **vscode 2021** in Win10 : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

--
[image]

```
  "key": "ctrl+shift+space",
  "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`editor.action.smartSelect.expand`, assigned to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> will expand your current selection, so inside a string, will expand to the current word, and to the whole string when pressed again. I think this is the proper shortcut to learn because it can also expand beyond the string to select ever more wrappers, which is a pretty neat thing to be able to do.

As of v1.44, there is no keyboard shortcut assigned to `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` anymore, as mentioned in the current accepted answer by Wosi.

Comment: I was wondering why there's *editor.action.smartSelect.grow* and *editor.action.smartSelect.expand*. By your answer, it sounds as they've deprecated the former to the benefit of the latter. Weirdly, both come up when intellisensing in the editor for *settings.json* and I've found surprisingly little information on that subject. Generally, I find the commands of VSCode to be poorly documented. Got any suggestion in that regard?

Comment: @KonradViltersten `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` is obsolete, it stays for compatibility I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The extension [BracketSelect](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chunsen.bracket-select) does the trick perfectly!
It selects **all text** between the nearest *matching quotes or brackets* **at once**. Press it twice, and it adds the delimiting elements (the quotes or brackets) to the selection. Press it once more and the selection grows it's way up.

Basically, it works like the `smartSelect` command, but with the neat difference that it selects all text inside the brackets or quotes at once, which to me is a way more common use case than the way `smartSelect` works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that all of the above answers do work, but they also select a space in front of the opening bracket, and selects the closing bracket.  Rather than actually selecting only the text between brackets.  You can test this by pressing command+[ and it will move an entire conditional, for example, rather than just the code between the brackets.  Something I commonly used in Coda when formatting code.

One solution to this I found, is a plugin called [Scoper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.scoper).

This highlights everything between brackets without actually highlighting it.  You can set the highlight color.  Then I can click inside the first bracket, hold down shift, and click before the closing bracket to actually highlight everything between the brackets, and exclude the brackets themselves.

Many people may not see a use case for this, but thought I'd post just in case it helps anyone as none of the current solutions worked for me.