# How do I select text inside of braces in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Atom I can select inside of brackets with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. How can I do this in Visual Studio Code? I've checked the keyboard bindings, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there in vscode an option to: Select everything between matching brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835012/is-there-in-vscode-an-option-to-select-everything-between-matching-brackets)

Comment: And see Feb., 2018 update to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835012/is-there-in-vscode-an-option-to-select-everything-between-matching-brackets/48676726#48676726

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 even better alternative commands in the keybinding file you might want to check out:

> editor.action.smartSelect.grow

and

> editor.action.smartSelect.shrink

They select everything in between the next boundary (quotes, brackets, curly braces...) and the selection grows to the next boundary when you hit the shortcut again.

Default shortcut is ctrl+shift+cmd+right / ctrl+shift+cmd+left, which is a bit too "finger heavy" for my taste, so you might want to rebind it (I use ctrl+up / ctrl+down).

Comment: thanks @kwood! I also redefined keybindings for those commands.

Comment: Thanks! I was one of my favourites in Sublime but was struggling to find it in vscode.

Comment: A nice keybinding option for Linux users is `ctrl+shift+m` to `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` and let `cursorUndo` (`ctrl+u`) make the shrinking.

Comment: I don't have such `editor.action.smartSelect.grow` commands. VS Code did not come with these commands. I tried pressing `cmd-shift-p` then searched for smartselect, and there's no command.

Comment: @trusktr Try a search in the keyboard settings UI.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So those commands don't always show in the command palette. That's a bummer. In Atom, everything is available in the command palette.  It would be convenient if VS Code did the same.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for selecting all text inside the braces.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>    for jumping between opening/closing braces (or) parentheses.