# How do I select the insides of div in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example. I have

```
<div class="wrap>
 <div class="fu">
  bar
 </div>
</div>
```

How do I select  with all it's contents with a shortcut key?

Notepad++ had this feature. When div contents get really long, it's annoying to scroll or collapse-select.

Answer (score 24):

You can select it with an Emmet command, if you have your cursor somewhere inside the first tag, just use `Emmet: Balance (outward)` and `Emmet: Balance (inward)`. If you are doing a lot of HTML, you can check for more Emmet commands if you simply type `Emmet:` in the command palette.

Because it's mentioned in the other answer:

What the "expand-region" plugin does, is somewhat supported by default, see this [answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908642/how-do-i-select-text-inside-of-braces-in-visual-studio-code/39911195#39911195)

This does **not** support shrinking/growing the selection around HTML-tags, but you can easily setup your shortcuts to use Emmet in HTML files and the aforementioned commands in every other file – on the same shortcut. Syntax for setting this is up looks like this (feel free to replace `ctrl+up` / `ctrl+down` to whatever you prefer):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.balanceOut",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html && editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl-down",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.balanceIn",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html"
},
```

Just for clarification, the `editorHasSelection` part allows to expand inside strings on the first key press (e.g. for selecting/editing tag attributes).

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you... or should I say Thank You*5?

Comment: Please note that it seems that correct actions names are now `editor.emmet.action.balanceIn` and `editor.emmet.action.balanceOut`.

Comment: @NicoPrat Good catch, the command name got changed with the recent Emmet update in VSCode. I edited the answer to reflect the changes. Thanks!

Comment: {
        "key": "cmd+shift+a", "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow", "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is still not supported out of the box for HTML.

You could install extension [expand-region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=letrieu.expand-region), set it up as stated on the page and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (or any other shortcut you choose) to select the content of the element.