# How to select highlighted text in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When navigating within a text, the VSCode is smart enough to highlight it like this.

[image]

Is there a command to select the whole text, to allow quick modification?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_shrinkexpand-selection

Comment: check this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835012/is-there-in-vscode-an-option-to-select-everything-between-matching-brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835012/is-there-in-vscode-an-option-to-select-everything-between-matching-brackets)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your suggestion does not relate.

Comment: @GeorgeBrountzas I need to select text between quotes, not brackets.

Comment: Search "expand" within that, not sure why the fragment doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use VScode extension Quick and Simple Text Selection

It has following key bindings:
Ctrl + K ' select everything between single quotes
Ctrl + K " select everything between double quotes

Comment: What an amazing extension!!!! All the various `Ctrl+K, x` commands to select quotes, braces and tags.

Answer (score 5):

Whipping out an extension for such a simple operation is bad practice.

The build-in keyboard shortcut for **smartSelect** is:
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

If you want to **shrink** your selection use: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

[image]