# Is there in vscode an option to: Select an entire section

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there in vscode a shortcut available which selects a whole section at once? I'd like a shortcut that would select one line of code if it's a single line, or if a section includes any closures it should collect everything including the preceding code before the opening and end at the the relevant closure.

Also see: [Is there in vscode an option to: Select everything between matching brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835012/is-there-in-vscode-an-option-to-select-everything-between-matching-brackets)

Edit:

Basically I want a shortcut to highlight this whole phrase at once:

```
if 1 == 1 {
    ** do stuff
}
```

that I can also use to highlight single lines of code:

```
** second do stuff
```

Comment: you can use regex >> grouping

Comment: you can try `Select By` https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by

Comment: any advice for writing the regex in a way that will scale well?