# How do I jump to matching brace in VS 2019?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019

As best as I can tell, Visual Studio 2019 completely removed the ability to jump to matching brace.

I tried the hotkey I've been using for years (Ctrl-]) and it changes indent instead (why would I need that? This is C#, not Python). I also tried looking up the KeyMap (Environment->Keyboard) setting and searching for match, and there was nothing relevant. As far as I can tell, Microsoft has completely removed this feature, but I wanted to confirm that [Fattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294884/fattie) and I are not the only ones with this problem.

(for reference, here is the [question for VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1501921/1739000) whose answer **no longer works** because the default keyboard shortcut has changed.)

EDIT: The setting still **exists**, but has been renamed to not contain the all-important keyword "match". See accepted answer.

Comment: I had this by "default", but I'm pretty sure I imported settings from 2017 and also have ReSharper installed, so one of those could have "fixed" it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The control is still there.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and lookup `Edit.GotoBrace` to see the current key combination for this feature:

[image]

You can set the key combination from the pictured menu.

Comment: You need to restart visual studio afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

just for the ones among us with non-us keyboard. On my keyboard, I need to press 'AltGr' to access "]". Therefore Ctrl+] doesn't work. Interestingly, VS has already compensated for that problem and changed the hotkey to Ctrl+`, which works nicely for me. You just need to know the hotkey has changed (depending on your keyboard).

Hope this saved a few minutes of your time ;)
Regards,
Eleusius.

Answer (score 0):

On a Finnish/Swedish keyboard the Edit.GotoBrace field is mapped to Ctrl+Å