# Visual Studio: Quickly go to bracket's closing pair

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-extensions, curly-braces

I'm working on Visual Studio 2017 and would like to know if there is any extension/shortcut to quickly go to a selected bracket's matching pair, or at least to get the closing bracket's line highlighted on the scroll bar on the right, so I can scroll there myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that on visual studio when you place your cursor on a bracket the editor highlights the matching bracket automatically, if it is not activated on your editor you can turn it on by going to *Tools > Options > Text Editor*
You can find more instructions and tips on the official documentation [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/navigating-code?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the other bracket is so far away that you can't see them on screen at the same time. And it's for those situations that I am asking this.

Comment: In this case you may find the answer you're looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio