# What is the keyboard shortcut for jumping to the matching tag in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2005, keyboard-shortcuts, tags

When editing HTML in Visual Studio, is there a keyboard shortcut for jumping to/from the matched html tag in much the same way that you can do so with matched brackets?

I've already been to the [Visual-Studio-Keyboard-Shortcuts Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts).

For example:

I want to move from <head> to </head> when I press a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It obviously knows what the matching tag is because it highlights it in the editor for you, but I don't know of any way of jumping between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a [shortcut key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa%28VS.80%29.aspx) for what you're trying to do.  I was able to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to work within .config files, but no luck on any html-based files (.aspx, .ascx, .master, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as for brackets for me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. If it's not working, check that the `Edit.GotoBrace` command is bound in the Keyboard options.

Comment: When I press Ctrl+] I get moved to the other end of the same tag.

Comment: What is `Edit.GotoBrace` bound to?

Comment: Edit.GotoBrace is bound to Ctrl+]

P.S. I am using Visual Studio 2005

Comment: I only have VS2008 installed - you could edit your question to clarify that you're asking about VS2005.