# Navigating through code with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm starting to feel the need to run fastly through code with keyboard shortcuts, to arrive faster where I want to make any changes (avoiding use of mouse or long times holding <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>).

I'm already using some:

- <kbd>Home</kbd>            - first position in current line
- <kbd>End</kbd>             - last position in current line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>   - first line of the entire code
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>    - last line of the entire code
- <kbd>Page Up</kbd>         - same vertical position, one screen above
- <kbd>Page Down</kbd>        - same vertical position, one screen below
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> - first line in current screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>    - last line in current screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd> - skipping word per word

What have you got ?

I use Visual Studio. (but I'm open to any answer, as I maybe can use others soon)

obs: I've searched through stackoverflow and didn't find a nice question with this content, nor a list of keyboard code searching. If it's repeated, I'm sorry for not finding it, I'm here in my best intentions.

This question is NOT about any shortcuts, and not only about visual studio, it's about running through code with shortcuts.

---

**Answers that suit the question so far:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> - jumps to last cursor position
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> - jumps to next cursor position
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> - Jumps to next occurance of the word the curson is in
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> - Same as the above, backwards.
- <kbd>F12</kbd> - Goes to  definition of method/variable the cursor is in
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> - Jumps to matching brace and select

I'll ad more as there are answers.

Comment: What editor, what platform (with its set of general conventions and keyboard shortcuts) are you talking about?

Comment: I use visual studio, but I'm open to any answer, as I maybe can use others soon.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For Visual Studio, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> is priceless (jump to last position).

Comment: Is there a way to go back again?

Comment: Yes, that's [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [-].

Comment: It is really irritating that this key combination has different behavior in Visual Studio Code. It results in zoom out of the code editor window instead.

Comment: I believe the default for this would be `Alt`+`←` in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 15):

I use a lot of keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio, and also a lot of Alt-key menu navigation.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> to repeat search, search backwards

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for the current word.

<kbd>F12</kbd> to jump to the definition of the current word.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to open the search window

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> to jump to a matching brace

<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> to jump to a matching brace and select

I also find I tend to use the <kbd>ALT</kbd>-key to navigate the menus.  Because you can see the underlines, it makes it easy to learn.  example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> (Edit/Find and Replace/Find in Files) takes you to Find in Files.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> then takes you to the scoping drop down.  3 arrow keys takes it to Find in Solution, or 4 takes it to Find in Project.

There's also the bookmarking shortcuts- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to toggle a bookmark, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> to clear them all, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> for the next and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> for the previous.

Some of the people I work with really like regions, but I don't, so <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> opens all the regions up.  However, I do like to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> to collapse a section of code.  It's really handy to collapse the current method, select the collapsed method and copy the whole thing to the clipboard.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> will collapse everything to definitions, which occasionally is nice.

Comment: The closing brace shortcut is gold.

Comment: How would you use the closing brace shortcut on an European keyboard?

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to find the next occurrence of whatever word your cursor is inside of.  So if you clicked on the first instance of the word 'occurrence' in my post and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>, it would take you down to the second one.

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Alt + Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + Down Arrow</kbd> are amazing commands. They move lines up and down. Saves a ton of keystrokes and you don't have to clobber your clipboard. It even works for multi-line selections.

<kbd>Alt + Shift + Arrow key</kbd> allow you to make a block selection. What many don't know is, if you have a vertical block selection (with zero width) and type, it will type into all the lines at the same time. Extremely useful.

If you wish to populate several lines with the same thing you can put it on the clipboard, make a vertical block selection across multiple rows, and paste into all the rows at the same time. This can also work to append to several rows at once, pasting into a selection that is to the right of the existing text.

<kbd>Ctrl+Del</kbd> deletes next word. However, if there is space after the cursor, it deletes all the space. Usually what you want when you have the cursor in the right place and the text is off to the right and that next word needs to be pulled over to the cursor.

<kbd>Ctrl+Backspace</kbd> deletes the previous word. Not particularly useful, but it's a good under-utilized shortcut. I see people mashing backspace all the time.

Although not strictly a keyboard shortcut, if you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click somewhere in the text editor, it will force the cursor to be there. If you type it will automatically put in spaces or tabs appropriately to make that text be there.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>F12</kbd> = Go To Definition of method/variable cursor is in.
Works well combined with Heinzi's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> answer to view definition of method then quickly go back to where you were using it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find over 100 answers to this very same question here:

[Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: it's not the same.. it's about ANY shortcut.. i'm searching for keyboard browsing shortcuts.

Comment: @MarceloRamires: It's not the _same_, but your question is a subset of the other question. You might not be able to use ALL of the shortcuts, but you should be able to search through that list and find the ones that are appropriate for your situation.

Comment: So let's flag "Common programming mistakes for PHP developers to avoid?" as a dupe because "Common mistakes in web development" exists.. perfect subset.. haha, just kidding. It's just that I find it too annoying moving my hand towards the mouse just to go somewhere near but hardly reachable through common commands.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

Will jump to next, previous code block (Method, class, etc.)
Might only be in ReSharper.

Comment: works only in reshaper.

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio, but using a lot of the ReSharper shortcuts. A few that I use heaps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - Go to type
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - Go to file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> - Go to symbol
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> - Go to method (in current file)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click) - Go to declaration
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> - Go to type declaration
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> - Find usage (or go to usage, if only one)

For the first four, resharper gives me a dropdown menu with options, filtered as I type, and they all support wildcards (`*`), and camel-hump navigation (typing `SPI` filters to just items such as SinglePassengerInfo, etc)

Comment: i'm aware. the above are all shortcuts to jumping to particular parts of code.

Comment: oh, sorry, i thought some of these were menu's or something.. and Thanks Very much!

Comment: Hm, I thought Ctrl+N was new file...

Comment: well yeah, as i said, i use a lot of the resharper shortcuts. ctrl+n is one of the conflicts, and i can't say i mind it. i use the goto file dialog way more than the new file dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I long for the day when VisVim gets to a good enough point to get me to buy it for Visual Studio (<3 VI keyboard commands).

Anyway, the command that I use the most in Vis Studio is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, which I have mapped to `Edit.GotoFindCombo`

Comment: so you select a word and press ctrll + d and it shows you the next one ?

Comment: @espais Have you tried Viemu? http://www.viemu.com/ I've used Viemu + Resharper since June and it makes a drastic difference in the speed I can navigate and manipulate code.

Comment: sorry, yea i meant viemu...i've tried it and liked it enough, but when i tried it there were too many commands missing for me to justify buying it

Comment: @Marcelo: no, it just puts the focus on a quick find combo box...i like it better than having to wait for the find dialog to popup!

Comment: This is an old question, as it this answer, but I have been using VsVim with great success https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaredParMSFT.VsVim

Answer (score 0):

[C# VS 2008 Keyboard Shortcut Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en)

[VB.NET VS 2008 Keyboard Shortcut Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255B8CF1-F6BD-4B55-BB42-DD1A69315833&displaylang=en)