# Can I jump back from the definition to the previous reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When debugging in Visual Studio 2015, after jumping from a reference of an identity to its definition, can I jump back from the definition to the previous reference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yup. There is a "Navigate backwards" command that will do what you want.

[image]

You can see where it is for me and it is part of the "Standard" shortcut bar. It can also be found under the "View" menu or the keyboard shortcut is `ctrl+-`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. 
This would bring you to the last position of the cursor.

The [original Answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41201037/5174469)
Did I get you right?

For more information on navigation by shortcuts [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888161/navigating-through-code-with-keyboard-shortcuts) is quite helpfull

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming that you have been doing things in sequence*, you can **Navigate Backwards**

### Keyboard Shortcut

Hitting `Ctrl + -` (Ctrl and minus at the same time)

---

### Visual Studio Toolbar GUI

Alternatively, you can also do this by hitting the back button on the toolbar

[image]

---

### Mouse Shortcut

Lastly, the "3rd" mouse button if you have one, usually on the left side. (The same mouse button that gets your browser to navigate backwards)