# Keyboard shortcut to comment/uncomment selected code in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2008, is there a keyboard shortcut to comment/uncomment selected lines of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for commenting
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> for uncommenting

For more good stuff, check [Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts).

Answer (score 1):

Look under the Edit->Advanced menu. I actually changed mine to CTRL-/, CTRL-/ so I can't remember what the original was.