# Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio for faster coding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio autocompletes brackets and tags and then shifts the cursor inside a bracket/tag upon creation. 
I usually have to hit `END` then `ENTER` to continue past the tag, it would be really useful to 'jump' over the closing tag/bracket and possibly to the next line.

[image]

Is there a fundamental keyboard shortcut I'm missing here in order to accomplish this?

Can't find this in the MSDN VS Keyboard Shortcut manual either.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Comment: Amol, don't understand why you downvoted. It's a fairly difficult thing to Google and it isn't in the Keyboard Shortcut list either. I've checked.

Comment: Hey, I have not down voted you...

Comment: Sorry then, I just assumed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut you are looking for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Pressing this will take you to the next line instead of inserting an enter, allowing you to move the cursor outside of the tag.