# Specific VS shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

I been using NetBeans since I started programming. Now, I'm learnig C++ and I have to use VS (2013).

The first things that I miss are some shortcuts like "add a semi colon at the end of the line", "click on top of a method call and the class where that method is open".

Are this shortcuts present on VS? If yes, how do I use them?

Thanks

EDIT

```
foo.setThing(getThing()?)
```

I'm talking when the cursor is where the "?" is and you whant to close the line(add a semi colon)...

In NetBeans you just do ";" and it does that for you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/98606/62576

Comment: Hm, the only shortcut I've ever missed was real convert-tabs-to-spaces, and it's easy to add to the menus. I'll look though, if nobody else comes up with answer.

Comment: @nervousDev: In Visual Studio you can use End + ; to add a semicolon at the end of the line. Actually this is an UNDOCUMENTED shortcut. ;-) See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) for a list of the documented shortcuts.