# Visual Studio shortcut to search menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I believe that there used to be a short to quickly find menu items.

Like if I wanted to search for `Source Control Explorer` I could use a shortcut to bring up a search box and type in `Source Control` and it'll find it for me.

It's similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> that searches for files and methods.

I can't find the shortcut anywhere.

This thread [Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts) does not have anything for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> to jump to the [Quick Launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh417697.aspx) search box.