# What's your favourite VS 2008 shortcuts?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Visual Studio 6 tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147339/visual-studio-6-tips-and-tricks)
>   [Visual Studio 2005 Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452/visual-studio-2005-shortcuts)
>   [Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts)

I am a big fan of shortcuts in VS2008, it can save a lot of time and keep your fingers on the keyboard instead of the mouse.

Recently I downloaded the entire list of [keyboard shortcuts for VS 2008](http://swami-k.blogspot.com/2009/01/visual-studio-2008-keyboard-shortcut.html) and went through them all finding my favourites.

Currently here are the top one's I use:

1. Shift + DEL: Deletes an entire line
2. Ctrl + Shift + F10: Brings up the Using / Resolution box
3. cw[tabx2]: Inserts Console.Writeline code
4. ctor[tabx2]: Inserts default constructor code

What other ones do people know that saves time / are actually useful?

Comment: Alt-F4 when the I call it a day

Comment: Ctrl + G, jump to line#; Shift + F12 find all references; F12 go to definition, Ctrl + I incremental search, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd> Jump to definition

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>Find al references

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MINUS</kbd>  Jump back to previous cursor location

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>MINUS</kbd> Jump forward to last cursor location

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>C</kbd> Comment out currently selected code

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>U</kbd> Uncomment currently selected code

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>F</kbd> Format selected code

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd> Format document

<kbd>F5</kbd>  Start Debugging

<kbd>F6</kbd>  Build Solution

<kbd>F7</kbd> Switch to code view

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F7</kbd> Switch to design view

These are the ones I use most.

PS. Microsoft released keybinding posters for Visual Studio.

- VS C# 2005 Keyboard Shortcut [Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C15D210D-A926-46A8-A586-31F8A2E576FE&displaylang=en)
- VS C# 2008 Keyboard Shortcut [Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5F902A8-5BB5-4CC6-907E-472809749973&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 3):

Incremental Search - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

Search your code, just like in Firefox/IE8. Doesn't work with regions however.

Comment: it does if you have selected "search hidden text" on a previous normal search.

Comment: Really? That didn't have any effect on incremental search last time I tried it, but I will have to try again. This could end the region debate in our company!

Comment: oups!!! no it doesnt. I wish i could at least have a way to expand all regions (the opposite of ctrl+m+o)

Comment: At least I'm not going crazy :)

Ctrl M, P will stop outlining, which has basically the same effect as expanding all

Comment: CTRL+M,P doesnt seem to expand anything. At least not in VS 2005 VB.NET i am currently working on. Will try it at home on VS 2008 and see how it goes...

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+. : Opens the current smart tag in the text editor. This saves sooo much time when you use smart tags.

By the way, the tab-tab things are code snippets rather than short-cuts. Shouldn't make a difference for this question though.

Comment: "using"... 'nuff said... +1 ;-p

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> : collapses all regions and methods

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> : toggle outlining for the current region or method

Answer (score 0):

Most of my "shortcuts" come from ReSharper and ViEmu, so R#'s Alt+Enter and various Vim features top my list.

Answer (score 0):

```
F5, F5, F5 and F5
```

Comment: That may be, but I can hand on heart, honestly say, it is the Visual Studio shortcut that I use the most.

Comment: CTRL + F5 runs your program but detaches it from the debugger - makes it faster :)

Comment: For some reason, in many cases, I click on the Debug button rather than press F5. Don't know, maybe it's because the coding (i.e. typing) phase is over then ;)

Comment: @OregonGhost: I too can't figure out why I dont press F5 and almost always click on debug button !! pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

Shift + F11 -> Set the Next Execution Statement [while debugging]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> > include namespace

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > Refactor, ecapsulate field

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> > build current project

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> > Quick  Watch in debugger

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> > navigate back and forward in code

<kbd>F2</kbd> > Refactor, Rename > my favorite one

Answer (score 0):

Shift + F5: Stop debugging

Answer (score 0):

I use Resharper that offers the major refactoring and search functionallity with different shortcuts.