# How can I remove a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Specifically, I am always hitting Ctrl-A instead of Ctrl-S which is really annoying because it loses your place in the code.  I *very rarely* actually want to select all of a file in Visual Studio, so I'd like to remove the keyboard shortcut so that Ctrl-A does nothing.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to Tools -> Options -> (select "Show all settings" checkbox) -> Environment -> Keyboard
- Type "Edit.SelectAll" in the text box labeled "Show commands containing"
- Click the Remove button to remove the shortcut Ctrl-A for that command

Answer (score 0):

```
Tools > Options > 'Show all settings' > Environment > Keyboard
```

Obtained from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452/visual-studio-2005-shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

By the way, ctrl-minus will take you back to your previous position in the code, and ctrl-shift-minus will take you forward.